# Could not create FileClient : Mapr DataBase

Tags: mapr

When retrieving my objects from the Mapr database in my program .
I get this error :

> 2018-09-10 15:19:56,0244 ERROR Cidcache fs/client/fileclient/cc/cidcache.cc:1611 Thread: 12922 MoveToNextCldb: No CLDB entries, cannot run, sleeping 5 seconds!
>   2018-09-10 15:20:01,0246 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:1104 Thread: 12922 Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Connection reset by peer(104)
>   com.palmyra.arch.exception.ProcessException: Could not create FileClient

and after this , the program exits .

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to initialize client for cluster 127.0.0.1:7222, error Connection reset by peer(104)

I think this message is pretty clear.  Your program is trying to connect to port 7222 on the local host where it's running and nothing is listening on that port so the connection attempt fails with error 104, connection reset by peer.

Generally, you shouldn't be setting the CLDB address to 127.0.0.1 since that always means the local host and the only host on which that address will work is the host on which the CLDB service is running.  You should be running the configure.sh script and specifying the hostnames of the servers where you run the CLDB with the -C option to that script.  Since there was no information provided about how you've setup the MapR software or the environment in which you are trying to run this application, I can only point you at the MapR documentation which walks through the steps for installing and setting up both the cluster servers as well as clients.

[MapR Documentation](https://mapr.com/docs)